# Proving trig identity $\tan(2x)−\tan(x)=\frac{\tan(x)}{\cos(2x)}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently stumped on proving the trig identity below:

$\tan(2x)-\tan (x)=\frac{\tan (x)}{\cos(2x)}$

Or, alternatively written as:

$\tan(2x)-\tan (x)=\tan (x)\sec(2x)$

Help on deriving it would be appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! What have you tried? Have you tried using the double angle formula for tangent?

Comment: No afford, and people giving their solutions, let him try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan2x-\tan{x}=\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}-\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin2x\cos{x}-\cos{2x}\sin{x}}{\cos2x\cos{x}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}\cos2x}=\frac{\tan{x}}{\cos{2x}}$$

Comment: That makes it very clear; thanks!

Comment: @Hamza Qayyum Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Using some [trig-identities](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/idents.htm) we have:
$$\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$$
and
$$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$
and
$$\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)-1$$
we have (on the left hand side):
$$\begin{align}\tan(2x)-\tan(x)&=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}-\tan(x)\\&=\frac{2\tan(x)-\tan(x)+\tan^3(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}\\&=\tan(x)\frac{1+\tan^2(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}\\&=\tan(x)\frac{1+\sec^2(x)-1}{1-\sec^2(x)+1}\\&=\tan(x)\left[\frac{2-\sec^2(x)}{\sec^2(x)}\right]^{-1}\\&=\tan(x)\left[2\cos^2(x)-1\right]^{-1}\\&=\tan(x)[\cos(2x)]^{-1}\\&=\tan(x)\sec(2x)\end{align}$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's a trigonograph:

[image]

$$\tan 2\theta = \tan\theta + \tan\theta \sec 2\theta$$

Comment: Wow that's really cool. Awesome tool for visualising the identity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\cos (2x)=\frac {1-\tan^2 (x)}{1+\tan^2 (x)} $$

$$\sin(2x)=\frac {2\tan (x)}{1+\tan^2 (x)} $$

thus
$$\sin(2x)-\tan (x)\cos (2x)=$$
$$\frac {2\tan {x}-\tan (x)+\tan^3 (x)}{1+\tan^2 (x)}$$
$$=\tan (x) $$ Done.